# Посоветуйте как лучше создать базу данных о людях/контактах

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, ms-access

Посоветуйте как лучше создать базу данных о людях/контактах (фамилия, имя, отчество, адрес, телефоны, адреса электронной почты, дата рождения и т.д.), с возможностью отслеживания смены адреса проживания, смены фамилии, то есть чтобы можно было узнать, например, по какому адресу проживал человек два года назад, какая фамилия у него тогда была 
 + тот факт, что некоторые типы информации могут быть и по несколько (например, номера телефонов). 
Кроме создания по таблице для каждого поля с информацией о человеке с указанием даты создания записи и сроком действия этой информации + поле yes/no для указания актуальности записи, какие еще есть варианты? На сколько правильный мой подход?
Базу думаю создать в Access. Заранее спасибо всем, кто не прошел мимо.

Persons

```
   -    ID
   -    Birthday
   -    …
```

PersonName

```
   -    ID
   -    PersonID
   -    Name
   -    StartDate
   -    EndDate
   -    Relevance (yes/no)
   -    …
```

Person{ABC}

```
   -    ID
   -    PersonID
   -    {ABC}
   -    StartDate
   -    EndDate
   -    Relevance (yes/no)
```

Буду рад если кто-то кто делал подобные бд, поделиться своим опытом/вариантом и расскажет с какими проблемами столкнулся.

Comment: По таблице на каждый вид данных перебор. Думаю вам нажна таблица с актуальными одиночными данными (ФИО и т.п.), дополнительные для телефонов и других множественных. А всю историю хранить отдельно в чем то типа EAV. Т.е. примерно такая таблица как вы нарисовали, только с полем "тип" что бы в ней можно было хранить информацию и по фио и по телефонам. Хрнаить в ней либо только старое, либо дублировать и актуальную. Просто выборка из EAV медленнее, если часто нужна актуальная инфа лучше вв получать из основной таблицы

Comment: Да, спасибо. Этот вариант мне кажется интересным, но как быть если у каждого типа информации о человеке есть свой подтип, например, номер телефона (мобильный, домашний, рабочий и т. д.) и эти подтипы не применимы к другим типам информации (например, адрес)?

Comment: Хм. это проблема. ну скажем можно несколько полей сделать на всякий случай, в зависимости от типа их заполнять. правда это все как то кривовато выглядит. с другой стороны, если эта история не так часто нужна, может и норм. Вопрос в том, сколько еще таких сцепленных атрибутов может встречаться и откуда берутся их значения, если просто закодированы в программе это пол беды, а если вдруг из других таблиц-справочников ("виды телефонов"), то ключ то не построишь, целостность не гарантируешь ...P.S. И Relevance в любом случае не нужно, дат достаточно, просто всерять с текущей.

Comment: @Mike, "И Relevance в любом случае не нужно, дат достаточно, просто всерять с текущей." – этот вариант и мне больше нравится). Спасибо.

Comment: Можно создать две таблицы, одна будет Persons со всеми полями вторая будет PersonsVersion (содержит все поля и дату актуальности) в которую триггером будут вставляться записи из первой таблицы при обновлении. При выборке данных смотреть на дату актуальности, если такова имеется, и в зависимости от даты получать записи

Comment: И да, еще небольшой совет, когда информация актуальна ставить дату окончания например 01.01.3000 (да, в моих системах будет проблема 3000 года :) ) Очень часто вижу, что в таких случаях ставят NULL, после чего все проверки выглядят дико (`start<=sysdate and (end >= sysdate or end is null)`) и главное, практически гарантируют медленную работу из за полного перебора таблицы. С 3000 годом поиск по `sysdate between start and end` отлично работает по индексу

Comment: я бы сделал 3 таблицы: первая - id физического лица (можно, конечно, еще какие-то столбцы, данные в которых не могут измениться), вторая -  id физлица + данные, которые могут быть только в единственном числе в конкретный отрезок времени (фио и тому подобное), дата начала действия записи, дата окончания. Третья - данные, которые могут быть во множественном числе: id физлица, тип, значение, дата начала, дата окончания. Если нужна была бы выборка в одну строку по физлицу, то объединение всех телефонов, имэйлов в одно значение делалось бы с помощью group_concat с группировкой по типу и id физлица.

Comment: В общем, тут основная проблема в том, как организовать таблицу с номерами телефонов и электронной почты. Просто сейчас вам нужны только номер телефона и почта, а завтра будет нужен скайп или еще какой-нибудь способ связи, поэтому лучше сделать эту таблицу более обобщенной, без отдельных столбцов "телефон", "почта" - просто Contacts(id, stype, svalue, dbegin, dend). Скажем, для телефона будет (1,'телефон','88005553535','01-01-2018','26-01-2018'), для почты (1,'почта','sportloto@ya.ru','01-01-2018','01-01-2099'), когда появятся новые способы связи - менять структуру таблицы не придется.